# R-Markdown Beamer

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

I am in serious trouble, I spent a day on this issue, would appreciate it if you could help me on this.
I am trying to make a beamer presentation using R Markdown. It was doing perfectly until a few days ago but now I have encountered this error every time I Knit. I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log df.log.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...ing: Your graphic driver \pgfsysdriver 
                                                  \space does not support tr...
l.532 ...lt}{0}{0}{\pgfmathresult}{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}
                                                  % 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile df.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See df.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

````
---
title: "Comparaison de performance de modèles"
subtitle: "Présentation de la problématique"
date: 2/6/2021
author: |
    | amirrea...
    | \scriptsize Master 2, Chargé d'études économiques et statistiques
output: 
     beamer_presentation:
        latex_engine : xelatex
        theme: "Montpellier"
        colortheme: "beaver"
        toc: FALSE
        slide_level: 4
        fig_width: 1
        fig_height: 1
        fig_caption: false
        includes:
            in_header: ../Presentation/header.tex
fontsize: 11pt
bibliography: ../Literature/bib.bib

---
```{r}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

# hello

some notes

# References
````

Here is the header tex:

```
% Colors
% \usepackage{colortbl}

% Change section names style
\titlegraphic{
  \vspace{-10mm}
  \flushright
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/lig_logo_1.png}
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/gael_logo_3.jpg}
  % \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/uga_logo.png} 
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/inp_logo.png} 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Load Packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Spacings
\usepackage{setspace}

% Tables
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

% Floats
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}

% Highlighting
\usepackage{soul}

% Horizontal page position
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Append pdfs
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Add latex chunks
\usepackage{docmute}

% Short toc
\usepackage{shorttoc}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\usepackage{minitoc} - incompatible with document class

% Referencing mutliple things with a single command - \cref
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Array
\usepackage{array}

% Multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

% Image insertion and colors
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Latex comments
\newenvironment{dummy}{}{}

% Fonts
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Museo}

% drawing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
% \usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\usepackage{calc}


% Add footline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{amirreza}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\insertshortdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute{}\hspace*{1em}
   %\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} % old version
    \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex} % new version without total frames
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

Here is the .tex file produced by r markdown rendering pdf file when I run it on texworks:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  11pt,
  ignorenonframetext,
]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=normal text.fg}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
% Prevent slide breaks in the middle of a paragraph
\widowpenalties 1 10000
\raggedbottom
\setbeamertemplate{part page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=16pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{part title}\insertpart\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection page}{
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{subsection title}\insertsubsection\par
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\AtBeginPart{
  \frame{\partpage}
}
\AtBeginSection{
  \ifbibliography
  \else
    \frame{\sectionpage}
  \fi
}
\AtBeginSubsection{
  \frame{\subsectionpage}
}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usetheme[]{Montpellier}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Comparaison de performance de modèles},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\newif\ifbibliography
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
% Colors
% \usepackage{colortbl}

% Change section names style
\titlegraphic{
  \vspace{-10mm}
  \flushright
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/lig_logo_1.png}
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/gael_logo_3.jpg}
  % \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/uga_logo.png} 
  \includegraphics[height = 8mm]{../images/inp_logo.png} 
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Load Packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Spacings
\usepackage{setspace}

% Tables
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

% Floats
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}

% Highlighting
\usepackage{soul}

% Horizontal page position
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Append pdfs
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Add latex chunks
\usepackage{docmute}

% Short toc
\usepackage{shorttoc}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\usepackage{minitoc} - incompatible with document class

% Referencing mutliple things with a single command - \cref
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Array
\usepackage{array}

% Multiple columns
\usepackage{multicol}

% Image insertion and colors
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Latex comments
\newenvironment{dummy}{}{}

% Fonts
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Museo}

% drawing
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
% \usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\usepackage{calc}


% Add footline
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{amirreza}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\insertshortdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute{}\hspace*{1em}
   %\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} % old version
    \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex} % new version without total frames
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title{Comparaison de performance de modèles}
\subtitle{Présentation de la problématique}
\author{amirrea\ldots{}\\
\scriptsize Master 2, Chargé d'études économiques et statistiques}
\date{2/6/2021}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{options}\NormalTok{(}\DataTypeTok{tinytex.verbose =} \OtherTok{TRUE}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
\end{frame}

\hypertarget{hello}{%
\section{hello}\label{hello}}

\begin{frame}{hello}
some notes
\end{frame}

\hypertarget{references}{%
\section{References}\label{references}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a [mre] that reproduces the problem and also include the intermediate .tex file in your question

Comment: Thanks for posting the rmarkdown file. Can you please also include the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I would avoid the `tabu` package. You also don't need any of the float related packages because beamer does not have a floating mechanism and be careful with your toc packages, beamer has its own mechanism and loading these packages might have undesired effects. Also beamer has its own columns mechanism, no need for the `multicol` package and `graphicx` is already loaded by default.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, I will follow them. The .tex file produced by r markdown is actually working when I run it by TeXworks.

Comment: I figured out that it is not the problem of header.tex, it is related to the R Markdown itself. I do not know how to address this issue.

Comment: Both your markdown and tex files work fine for me. My guess would be that if you compile with texworks, you are maybe not using tinytex but another tex distribution with more up-to-date packages etc. To see if this might be the cause, make a diff of the .log files

Comment: samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you very much for following up. In fact, I needed to remove tinytex and install it again, the problem is solved.